# Searching for specific users created less than 30 days

Tags: powershell, date, active-directory, filtering, querying

I am trying to create a line of code that will search for a specific user (from a list). My current code below is not working as it doesn't bring back anything when you run it. However, if I remove the whenCreated field it finds something. The user I am testing this with was created yesterday so not sure why it is not being returned. Any help always appreciated.

```
$startDate = (Get-Date).Date
$endDate   = $startDate.AddDays(-30).Date
Get-ADUser -filter {Surname -eq $e -and physicalDeliveryOfficeName -eq $site -and whencreated -ge $enddate} | Select-Object samAccountName -ExpandProperty samAccountName
```

Comment: Testing for _whenCreated_ this way works for me. Try to run `Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated <youruser>` to check what the value is, maybe it just does not meet the conditions.

Comment: Did my answer help you at all?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first get all users created on or after your `$enddate` and who'se Office property is equal to your variable `$site` and then eventualy filter those that can be found in your array if last names.
Also, `-Filter` should be a **string**, not a scriptblock.

Try

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Office -eq '$site' -and Created -ge $enddate" -Properties Office, Created | 
Where-Object { $yourListOfLastNames -contains $_.Surname }
```

If need be, you can pipe through to a `Select-Object` to obtain only the properties you need for your output.
By default, Get-ADUser outputs objects with these properties:

```
DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName
```

and in this case we've extended that to also have `Office` (= physicalDeliveryOfficeName) and `Created` (= whenCreated converted to DateTime)